# In Jenkins, Is there a way to execute a pipeline when the source branch of a PR is updated?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent { docker { image 'node:10.16' } }
  stages {
    stage('PR To Dev') {
      when {
        changeRequest target: 'dev'
      }

      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
        sh 'npm run lint'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to run linting upon every PR made (on Github). This pipeline works and runs as intended when I make the initial PR to the dev branch. However, subsequent commits to the open PR are ignored by Jenkins, which defeats the usefulness of the initial lint check. How can I configure Jenkins to lint upon any updates to a branch that has an open PR to the dev (or any arbitrary) branch?

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this goal is possible. It depends greatly on the plugin that you are using to integrate GitHub with Jenkins, and how you configure GitHub to use Jenkins' webhooks.

On the GitHub end, you can configure to trigger the webhook on different events. Default config is `Push events (to any branch, whether on PR or not)`, `All events (these can have many false positives)`, and the option to `Select individual events (find your right balance between events coverage and false positives)`

[image]

On the Jenkins end, some plugins will offer more customization options to discard unnecessary triggers, for example to avoid triggering a project on PR updates of the title or description (instead of code), etc.

I, personally, use the [Generic Webhook Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) on the Jenkins end and then I analyze the json of the webhook to determine whether to run a job or not